# Highcharter plot updates only after second click - R Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs, r-highcharter

This is my Code, similar like the question I already posted today. Now I have another issue I can not get my head around. When I click the `actionButton` to update the chart, the chart only updates after the second click. The `print` statement works after the first click. What is going wrong here?

```
library(highcharter)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

df <- data.frame(
    a = floor(runif(10, min = 1, max = 10)),
    b = floor(runif(10, min = 1, max = 10))
)


updaterfunction <- function(chartid, sendid, df, session) {

    message = jsonlite::toJSON(df)
    session$sendCustomMessage(sendid, message)

    jscode <- paste0('Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("', sendid, '", function(message) {
        var chart1 = $("', chartid, '").highcharts()

        var newArray1 = new Array(message.length)
        var newArray2 = new Array(message.length)

        for(var i in message) {
            newArray1[i] = message[i].a
            newArray2[i] = message[i].b
        }

        chart1.series[0].update({
            // type: "line",
            data: newArray1
        }, false)

        chart1.series[1].update({
        //   type: "line",
          data: newArray2
      }, false)

      console.log("code was run")

      chart1.redraw();
    })')

    print("execute code!")
    runjs(jscode)
}




# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Update highcharter dynamically"),
    #includeScript("www/script.js"),
    useShinyjs(),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            actionButton("data", "Generate Data")
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           highchartOutput("plot")
        )
    )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {


    observeEvent(input$data, {

        df1 <- data.frame(
            a = floor(runif(10, min = 1, max = 10)),
            b = floor(runif(10, min = 1, max = 10))
        )

        updaterfunction(chartid = "#plot", sendid = "handler", df = df1, session = session)

    })


    output$plot <- renderHighchart({

        highchart() %>%

            hc_add_series(type = "bar", data = df$a) %>%
            hc_add_series(type = "bar", data = df$b)

    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Just a workaround, but nevertheless: you could set `ignoreNULL = FALSE` for your `observeEvent`.

Comment: thank you, it works. Do you know why exactly my code does not work without it? Because I create "df1" inside the `observeEvent` ?. Sometimes I feel pretty stupid even after that much time using shiny...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is, that you are attaching the event handler for your plot after `observeEvent(input$data, {...})` is executed for the first time (actually you are adding a the CustomMessageHandler after every button click). Accordingly the event handler isn't already attached during the first button click (and can't react).

If you initialize the `CustomMessageHandler` **once** on session-startup and only send new messages on a button click it works as expected:

```
library(highcharter)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

df <- data.frame(
  a = floor(runif(10, min = 1, max = 10)),
  b = floor(runif(10, min = 1, max = 10))
)

updaterfunction <- function(sendid, df, session) {
  message = jsonlite::toJSON(df)
  session$sendCustomMessage(sendid, message)
}

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Update highcharter dynamically"),
  #includeScript("www/script.js"),
  useShinyjs(),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("data", "Generate Data")
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      highchartOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  sendid <- "handler"
  chartid <- "#plot"

  jscode <- paste0('Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("', sendid, '", function(message) {
        var chart1 = $("', chartid, '").highcharts()

        var newArray1 = new Array(message.length)
        var newArray2 = new Array(message.length)

        for(var i in message) {
            newArray1[i] = message[i].a
            newArray2[i] = message[i].b
        }

        chart1.series[0].update({
            // type: "line",
            data: newArray1
        }, false)

        chart1.series[1].update({
        //   type: "line",
          data: newArray2
      }, false)

      console.log("code was run")

      chart1.redraw();
    })')

  runjs(jscode)


  observeEvent(input$data, {

    df1 <- data.frame(
      a = floor(runif(10, min = 1, max = 10)),
      b = floor(runif(10, min = 1, max = 10))
    )

    updaterfunction(sendid = sendid, df = df1, session = session)

  })


  output$plot <- renderHighchart({

    highchart() %>%

      hc_add_series(type = "bar", data = df$a) %>%
      hc_add_series(type = "bar", data = df$b)

  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In the end that's also what `ignoreNULL = FALSE` does: It attaches the `CustomMessageHandler` during session-startup.

Please also check this useful [article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-send-message.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just Add `ignoreNULL=FALSE` in `observeEvent` function-

I noticed @ismirsehregal mentioned this trick in the comments.

Working Code-

```
library(highcharter)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

df <- data.frame(
  a = floor(runif(10, min = 1, max = 10)),
  b = floor(runif(10, min = 1, max = 10))
)


updaterfunction <- function(chartid, sendid, df, session) {

  message = jsonlite::toJSON(df)
  session$sendCustomMessage(sendid, message)

  jscode <- paste0('Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("', sendid, '", function(message) {
        var chart1 = $("', chartid, '").highcharts()

        var newArray1 = new Array(message.length)
        var newArray2 = new Array(message.length)

        for(var i in message) {
            newArray1[i] = message[i].a
            newArray2[i] = message[i].b
        }

        chart1.series[0].update({
            // type: "line",
            data: newArray1
        }, false)

        chart1.series[1].update({
        //   type: "line",
          data: newArray2
      }, false)

      console.log("code was run")

      chart1.redraw();
    })')

  print("execute code!")
  runjs(jscode)
}




# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Update highcharter dynamically"),
  #includeScript("www/script.js"),
  useShinyjs(),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("data", "Generate Data")
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      highchartOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {


  observeEvent(input$data, ignoreNULL = FALSE, {

    df1 <- data.frame(
      a = floor(runif(10, min = 1, max = 10)),
      b = floor(runif(10, min = 1, max = 10))
    )
    print(df1)
    updaterfunction(chartid = "#plot", sendid = "handler", df = df1, session = session)

  })


  output$plot <- renderHighchart({

    highchart() %>%

      hc_add_series(type = "bar", data = df$a) %>%
      hc_add_series(type = "bar", data = df$b)

  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: thanks, ismirsehregal posted the answer in the comment. Can you tell me what exactly is going on there? If I understand what´s going on i´m pretty happy to accept that answer ;-)

Comment: @DSGym Your plot isn't getting updated for first button click because your `df` is already plotting chart when you open your app and when you click on button, it creates the same plot using `df1`.

Comment: @DSGym you can change data in `df` to test it.